# GNU: Accessing a corrupted shared library error

Tags: linux, assembly, linker, x86, gnu

here is something super simple:

My code (p1.s):

```
    .intel_syntax noprefix
.arch i386
.data
poruka:
    .asciz "Zdravo svete!\n"
kraj_poruke:

.equ duzina_poruke, kraj_poruke - poruka

.text
.extern write
.extern exit
.globl _start

_start:
push duzina_poruke
push offset poruka
push 1
call write
add esp, 12

push 0
call exit

.end
```

The commands I use to assemble and link the files:

```
as -o p1.o p1.s
ld -o p1 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 p1.o -l c
```

After these commands, I have the p1.s, p1.o and p1 files all in the directory where I want them.

The error I get:

```
bash ./p1 : Accessing a corrupted shared library.
```

Why? :D
Thanks in advance!

Could someone please explain to me why this doesn't work? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you are on a 64 bit system. If you want to create a 32 bit program then use `as --32` and `ld -melf_i386`. Also note that if you want to use libc you should use entry point `main` not `_start` and use `gcc -m32` to compile and link so everything gets set up correctly and you avoid such mysterious errors.

Comment: Hey, I've tried (btw, yes I'm on a 64bit system):

ld -melf_i386 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 p1.o -l c

but now I get the error:

ld: cannot find -lc

whats up with that

Comment: You don't have the 32 bit C library installed.